# How to make the keyboard hide when tap the other control in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin

I Have an entry and listview inside stack. Listview contains checkbox, label and delete icon as button. After tap the entry then i try to delete the item in the listview, immediately keyboard disappears but white space is there. After that white space occupies half of the page.

Delete button having command and clicked event in xaml. Command to delete the icon. Clicked event to unfocus the entry. Befoe keyboard hiding properly command is triggering.

After tapping the delete button, i need to clear the focus of the entry to hide the keyboard, then only command event should trigger for deleting the item.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear focus on the entry add this in your button command:

```
yourEntryName.UnFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Command is actually executed before the event is triggered.
Also, it is not recommended to have an event and command attached to the same control.
My suggestion would be to try to stick with the command in a way that you can access your entry in your ViewModel.
If this is not possible for whatever reason, try something like this:

```
private void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myEntry.Unfocus(); //unfocus part
    myViewModel.DeleteCommand.Execute(null); //execute the command from the VM part
}
```

And then remove your Command binding since you are executing it this way.